# mongo deleteMany; how to debug result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Node with Mongoose.

Here's the deleteMany() I'm attempting to debug:

**Code:**

```
  const result = await Follow.deleteMany({
    $or: [
      { userFollowingAnother: req.user.id },
      { userThatIsFollowed: req.user.id },
    ],
  });

  console.log("result: " + result.acknowledged);
```

**Details:**

The result is not returning any value unfortunately. (returns undefined)
Also, the deleteMany is not working, as the documents still exist in the "Follow" collection afterwards.

The [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) generally indicates that a response is provided, and even provided an example, but I can't seem to access the result object's data or message.

**Goal:** A working query, but more importantly, a method for debugging the result, or at least accessing some sort of result.

***Update -*** **Fixed:**  I was missing a simple await statement prior to the Mongoose call.  I've updated the code to reflect the fixed version, as my question had to do with debugging.

Comment: always try to write your code in try catch block, after that post your error in your question.

Comment: @turivishal Always a safe common-sense suggestion.  In my case, I used a try-catch in a prior version; I've fixed it now with a simple 'await' statement prior to the code block returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-set

Use Something like this to,

Enable logging collection methods + arguments to the console

```
mongoose.set('debug', true)
```

Use custom function to log collection methods + arguments

```
mongoose.set('debug', function(collectionName, methodName, ...methodArgs) {});
```

Comment: This helped: turning on logging globally at the middleware level is sort of a blunt instrument, but it bypasses the async / sync considerations with manual console statements.